# TimeValue equivalent for periods longer then 24 hours

Tags: datetime, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

in my database the time someone has worked is stored in a certain amount of minutes. In my report I list those minutes in the format HH:MM. I do this by making use of the following function:

```
Function (numberVar numberToBeConverted)

local TimeVar result;

local StringVar hh := ToText((Truncate( numberToBeConverted ) / 60), "0");
local StringVar mm := ToText((Truncate( Abs(numberToBeConverted) ) mod 60), "00");
local StringVar ss := '00';

Local StringVar t:= hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;

if istime (t) 
then result := TimeValue (tijd)
else result := TimeValue ("23:59:59");

result
```

I would like to preserve the datatype (time) but would like to be able to list duration longer then 24 hours (i.e. a workweek).

is this possible?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, CR's time format doesn't support what you want to do.  Try my [ElapsedTime()](http://cogniza.com/wordpress/2005/11/29/crystal-reports-elapsedtime-function/) custom function, instead.

** edit **

If the field returns the # of seconds, you could make use of its Display String formula.  Right click the field, choose 'Format Field...', then the 'Common' tab, then the button to the right of the 'Display String:' text; enter the following text:

```
//CurrentFieldValue assumed to be in seconds
ElapsedTime(CurrentFieldValue)
```

With this approach, you'll be able to have the formatting that you desire and still be able to use the field itself in calculations.

Comment: I came up with something similar. I would like to preserve the time datatype however in order to be able to make calcualtions with it. I guess i will have to accept that i will have a lot of display formulas (which call your elapsedTime fucntion)